# Using an array to access (deeply) nested object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given javascript object:

```
obj = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: 3
           }
       }
   }
```

I can access the deepest property as follows: `obj['a']['b']['c']` or `obj.a.b.c`. Now I want to access this using an array `['a', 'b', 'c']`. How can I access the same object property using this array?

Note: the method does not have to "safe", so no need to check for: typeError: cannot read property ... of undefined.

Comment: Maybe using recursion?

Comment: Yes, I can come up with a recursive solution but the problem seems so basic that I am afraid that I am missing something super obvious. (And I already need this as part of another recursive problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `reduce` method and pass your object as accumulator param.

```js
const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 3
    }
  }
}

const key = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function get(obj, key) {
  return key.reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
    return r[e] || (a[i + 1] ? {} : undefined)
  }, obj)
}

console.log(get(obj, key))
```

Comment: Im just trying to find away to access the object in this way but then also mutate that object, but I can't seem to get that to work.

Comment: There are lots of different options based on your requirements how you want to set new value but you could start with something like this  https://jsfiddle.net/syathrdg/3/, also take a look at lodash set method.